# T-SQL Gaps with strings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a database table with a column, clnum, that is varchar. It is numeric, but can contain leading zeroes. Given user input of number X in a C#.Net program, I need to determine what the next number is that does not exist in the table and display it to the user. This is SQL Server 2008. What I can do is strip off any leading zeroes, pass the resulting number to a T-SQL stored procedure, and do this:

```
CREATE    PROCEDURE [dbo].[getNextClientNum] 

@ModelNumber AS int
AS

;WITH UsedNumbers (clnum, clname1)

AS

(
    SELECT clnum, clname1 
    FROM QueuedClientMatters
),

OrderedNumbers (clnum, clnum_int, clname1)
AS
(
    SELECT TOP 500000 clnum, CAST(clnum AS int) AS clnum_int, clname1 
    FROM UsedNumbers
    WHERE CAST(clnum AS int) > @ModelNumber
    ORDER BY clnum
)

SELECT TOP 1 previd
FROM (SELECT clnum_int, LAG(clnum_int) OVER (ORDER BY clnum) previd
FROM OrderedNumbers) q
WHERE previd <> clnum_int - 1
ORDER BY clnum_int
```

I would then add leading zeroes back to previd so that its length is 6 (all clnums are always 6 digits) in my C# program and display it. But is there a way to get around stripping off the leading zeroes and then adding them back?

Comment: Have you considered adding a computed column to the table to provide the integer value of `clnum`? It can be persisted and indexed.

Comment: The table is part of our accounting system, and I wouldn't be allowed to do that. Otherwise, that'd be a great idea, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to strip off the leading zeros before converting to an int, that will happen automatically during the conversion.

Using SQL, you can easily add them back afterward using `REPLACE(STR(FieldName,6),' ','0')`

The only real alternative is to store the value in the table as a string so you don't loose the zeros.

Comment: Thank you! It hadn't occurred to me to add the zeroes back in in T-SQL. You saved me some coding.